# A query related to activiti

Tags: activiti

I have just started exploring Activiti, so my question may be noobish.

I have a process definition wherein I have defined a subprocess.
Subprocess has 2 user tasks defined. After completion of 1st user task(UT1), second one(UT2) starts. Subprocess in itself has following confg:

```
<subProcess id="..." name="...">
  <multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics isSequential="false" activiti:collection="#{parameters.ids}" activiti:elementVariable="input"></multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics>
  <userTask id="UT1" name="..." activiti:candidateGroups="..." activiti:category="..." activiti:priority="...">
    ...
  </userTask>
  <userTask id="UT2" name="..." activiti:candidateGroups="..." activiti:category="..." activiti:priority="...">
    ...
  </userTask>
  ...
  ...</subProcess>
```

So, for every n UT1 tasks, there are equal number(n) of UT2 tasks.

Now I need to change this arrangement in a way that for n UT1 tasks, only a percentage of n tasks are created for UT2. So, for every n UT1 tasks, there are x% of n UT2 tasks.

Is this possible by changing process definition file itself? Or do I need to take some alternate approach, like running some batch?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously there is a condition of some sort that will determine if a UT2 task is required.
Therefore, you should be able to use a decision step to determine whether to create a UT2 task based on some logic.

Answer (score 0):

Use decision table for logical interpretation, which will decide when the second user task should be started.